# Restocking items at the start of a 3-day cycle

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

Every time you turn back time to the start of the 3-day cycle, you lose all of the replenishable items. Items that you may need for puzzles in the next cycle.

So my question is, what is the easiest way to restock on regular items that may aid me in my adventure, like Deku Sticks, arrows and bombs at the start of a new cycle?

Comment: Termina Field has a lot of bushes near the town entrances that drop random stuff.

Answer (score 8):

You can more than easily restock on the more important stuff, such as arrows and bombs by breaking random crates or vases or by slashing grass anywhere in Termina.

However, if you want a reliable (and still easy) way to restock, you can always try to get the two silver ruppees in Clocktown to buy what you need from the Trading Post or the Bomb Shop.

The two silver ruppees can be found at the following locations:

- East Clocktown: Starting at the entrance to the secret passage to the Observatory, go directly south, up the stairs, then jump over the platforms until you have no other choice but to go right (West). The ruppee is in a chest.
- Secret passage to the Observatory: When you reach the waterway, go left (instead of right). You'll notice cracks on the wall: Use the Bomb Mask or a bomb (if you have one) to reveal the chest in which to find the ruppee. If you use the Bomb Mask, you can explode without suffering damage by brandishing your shield while exploding (<kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>).

Those chests will always contain a silver ruppee every time you start a new cycle, and are therefore a great way to farm ruppees safely.

Using the following map, the two chests are denoted by a green `5` and a green `6`.

[image: Map of Clocktown]

Comment: I tried rolling around Termina field as a Goron but it only yielded magic refills and bombs. Does grass drop different items depending on how you destroy, or is that a Termina Field-thing?

Comment: @CodedMonkey. Drops are likely influenced by a number of different factors. Rolling as a Goron yields more magic (to recover the magic you consume while rolling), hearts drop more often when you're hurt, arrows and bombs can be found more easily in places where you might actually need them, etc. I'm not 100% sure about that, but that's what I've observed.

Comment: True, unfortunately that doesn't help if there's nothing to break in sight whenever you need something. Who knew an item shop in Zelda didn't have to be reduntant.

Comment: The best way to make money is the Zora game in the Great Bay Coast.

Answer (score 0):

Try cutting the bushes near an owl statue outside the clock town. They contain arrows bombs and fairy!! But for that you need to have song of soaring so you can grab those things quickly.

Do something like this.

1]soar to snow head temple entrance. There breaking the snow blocks(elliptical looking) gives magic arrows bombs and fairy.

2] soar near the racetrack of gorman brothers (the path that leads to ranch), again cutting the bushes gives you bomb fairy and arrows.

And so on.

Keep repeating the process until you completely restock your arrow bomb and all

Comment: Well this was the case in the  n64. And I hope this mechanic remains in 3d version